# Linux SetSockOpt error 22

Tags: linux, delphi, сокет

Создал сокет, принимаю пакеты через recv. Но если мне нужно завершить прием, то у меня не получиться выйти, т.к. recv ждет. Из этой ситуации можно выйти используя **SetSockOpt(FSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, @FPSocketTimeOut, Len)**; В Windows нормально отрабатывает, а вот в **Linux возвращает ошибку 22**. Как я понял, то ошибка означает, что аргументы не те передаю. Стал копаться в документации. 3-им параметром передается вместо указателя на Integer структура TimeVal. Вот что у меня получилось, но все равно не работает. Где ошибка?

```
type
  TTimeVal = record
    tv_sec: Integer; 
    tv_usec: Integer;  
  end;

  PTimeVal = ^TTimeVal;

new(PSocketTimeOut);
PSocketTimeOut^.tv_sec:= 0;
 PSocketTimeOut^.tv_usec:= FSocketTimeOut;
 Len:=  SizeOf(TTimeVal);
 if SetSockOpt(FSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, PSocketTimeOut, Len) = -1 then
errCode:= GetLastError();
 writeln('errCode = ' + errCode.ToString);
```

Comment: по идее `tv_sec` и `tv_usec` (по крайней мере на amd64) должны быть типа long т.е. 64-х битного...

Comment: да, вы правы. в Posix.SysTime объявлен тип timeval. Это решило проблему.